# Unable to add managed metadata property when uploading XLSX file programatically

Tags: 2013, development, file-upload, drop-off-library

I have this code to upload files to Sharepoint and adding some properties:

```
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPList dropOffLibrary = web.Lists["Drop Off Library"];
        SPFolder dropOffFolder = dropOffLibrary.RootFolder;
        //Create the filename
        string sharePointFileName = fileToUpload.File.Name;
        //Get the content
        var fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload.File.FullName);
        // Upload document
        SPFile file = dropOffFolder.Files.Add(sharePointFileName, fileContents, false);
        SPListItem item = file.Item;
        //Add metadata
        item["Property1"] = fileToUpload.Property1;
        item["Property2"] = fileToUpload.Property2;
        item["DocumentType"] = term.TagId.ToString();
        item.SystemUpdate();
        file.CheckIn(string.Empty);
```

This works perfect for PDF's and xls files. But there's something strange with xlsx files: the managed metadata property (DocumentType) stays empty (its a term form the termstore). Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it thanks to a co-worker (he should get the credits here):
Only the Id of the term is not enough. You need to add some extra info:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the taxonomy field value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">The item.</param>
        /// <param name="fieldName">Name of the field.</param>
        /// <param name="labelGuidPairFieldValue">The label GUID pair field value.</param>
        public static void SetTaxonomyFieldValue(SPListItem item, string fieldName, string labelGuidPairFieldValue)
        {
            //Get the field as a Taxonomy Field and create a Taxonomy Field Value using the label guid pair
            TaxonomyField taxonomyField = item.Fields.GetField(fieldName) as TaxonomyField;
            TaxonomyFieldValue taxonomyFieldValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue(taxonomyField);
            taxonomyFieldValue.PopulateFromLabelGuidPair(labelGuidPairFieldValue);
            //Set the taxonomy field to contain the Taxonomy Field Value            
            item[taxonomyField.InternalName] = taxonomyFieldValue;
            //Set the associated hidden text field with the label guid pair
            item[taxonomyField.TextField] = labelGuidPairFieldValue;
        }

Helper.SetTaxonomyFieldValue(item, "Internal Name column", docGroup.DocumentTypeTerm);

with docGroup.DocumentTypeTerm:

        private static string GetDocumentTypeTermInMetadataFormat(Group termGroup, int documentTypeId)
        {
            string documentType = RecordsManager.GetDocumentTypeText(documentTypeId);
            Term term = GetRootTerm(termGroup, "YourTerm", documentType); //Function to get the specific term
            return string.Format("{0}|{1}", term.Name, term.Id);
        }
```